# OCaml Error: Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?)

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have rewritten Scheme code that computes integer log, base 2 in OCaml. Upon compilation, I repeatedly get an error that says "Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?).".

I am a beginner with both of these languages as this is an assignment for one of my classes.

Scheme code:

```
(define log2
  (lambda (n)
    (if (= n 1) 1 (+ 1 (log2 (quotient n 2))))))
```

OCaml code:

```
let rec log2 n = 
  match n with 
  | 1 -> 1 
  | n -> 1 + log2 (n mod 2);;
```

Comment: Can you explain steb-by-step how you think each function should work? I don't know scheme. but it's pretty obvious to me that the OCaml code will get stuck on `0 mod 2 = 0`

Comment: @glennsl we are only using numbers 1-100. Also I have already corrected it using advice given below. Thank you though!

Comment: It's recursion., so`0` isn't required as initial input. `2 mod 2 = 0`, which leads to `0 mod 0 = 0`, and then around you go ad infinitum. Any input that eventually goes through 2 will therefore recurse infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

The scheme code has `quotient` and you have rendered this in OCaml with `mod`. This seems wrong. You want integer division, I would assume, which is `/` in OCaml.

Comment: Even with that modification, it looks like this is still infinitely recursive for any case where `n` is `0`.

Comment: @ChrisDutton we are only using numbers 1-100.

Comment: @Jeffrey thank you for your reply. I believe that I was confused at first about what needed to be found - remainder or modulo.